# RiscOs under QEMU

Tags: emulation, windows, qemu, riscos

I'm trying to use QEMU to emulate RiscOs under Windows7 or later.

Taking as a start point the Windows download to emulate Raspbian from [Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/rpiqemuwindows/).

Simply changing the `.img` file that is invoked by `run.bat` to the RiscOs `.img` that comes with NOOBS doesn't work as the boot routine still loads some linux load routine.  The documentation within the download package is just a long list of option codes.  I can't decode the options without some more documentation.

RiscOs is not listed on the Official QEMU supported OS list at [Claunia](http://www.claunia.com/qemu/) so I suspect there may not be much call for it!

Has anyone achieved this trick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [blog post](http://sinrega.org/?p=127) about how to boot RiscOS in QEMU. The trick is that you have to use custom QEMU (not the upstream one). For sure it should work using [blog author's tree](https://github.com/slp/qemu), but it was't updated for quite some time. I think it can also work on [Torlus tree](https://github.com/Torlus/qemu).

It also means that you have to go through painful compilation process under Windows or use Linux. I don't have checked method for that, so I can't give you valid link.